# Is there anything like an Arcane Archer in the Player's Handbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranged-attack, archetype

In the D&D Next playtest, there was a feat that allowed character to imbue arrows with certain types of spells. The one in the playtest let an arcane caster attach a spell to an arrow and the spell would go off if the arrow hit.

I can't find this feature in the final *Player's Handbook*. Is there anything like it in the final version of the rules (in a subclass or something)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xanathar's Guide to Everything added a class path for fighters named Arcane Archer, but it doesn't resemble the play test mechanics in any meaningful way.

You could make a bow-wielding wizard and simply flavor your spells as using your bow if you so desired, possibly also taking feats like War Caster (to cast while wielding your bow), or Spell Sniper (for longer range on your spells).